# Is there a way to perform a callback for each row read in read.csv in R?

Tags: r

I'm doing a simple read.csv call, and I have been able to use colClasses to specify the data type in each column (which halts the load if any column can't be converted into the specified data type, which is good!).  However, I'd like to go a step further and be able to perform a validation callback for each row read.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
csvData <- {};
for (def in cacheEnv$requiredFiles) {
  # load each CSV file and store in csvData
  currentCsv <- read.csv(paste(directoryPath, def$name, sep=""),
                         header = TRUE,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                         colClasses = def$columns);
  csvData[[def$name]] <- currentCsv;
}
```

What I'd like to do is have a function invoked on each row that can either throw an error (fail-fast) or even be able to re-write the read values into a transformed form (such as if you wanted to do an upper case transform on a value) before reading it into the resulting dataframe.

Something that would look like this:

```
csvData <- {};
for (def in cacheEnv$requiredFiles) {
  # load each CSV file and store in csvData
  currentCsv <- read.csv(paste(directoryPath, def$name, sep=""),
                         header = TRUE,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                       colClasses = def$columns,
                       callback = def$validateFunc);
  csvData[[def$name]] <- currentCsv;
}
```

Where the callback is just a function that can take the column values as a parameter, and do something with the values (or throw an error).

The reason for doing it this way (instead of reading in the entire file and then transforming it after) is that the file might be very large, and I'd like to fail sooner rather than later.  But I think a workaround for smaller files would be to just read it all in, and then transform it in-memory after loading.

But a row-by-row callback would be nice if anyone has a solution for this!

Comment: `read.csv()` is already fail-fast, it it chokes on a bad line, it will die right there.  This function is intended to be used for heavy lifting of data into R.  But I think the validation etc. should happen elsewhere after the read has completed.  If you want to catch an error, you can use try-catch.  Anyway, if it fails on a given line, you probably won't be able to recover.

Comment: Beyond the wrong value type (like it finds a char on an interger line) can I make it fail if it encounters something that doesn't match a regex, for example?  That's the question: a custom rowback handler that might throw an error or do another action.

Comment: I should also add: i want to leverage the fail-fast nature of read.csv(). I want to be able to have a call back method throw an error (thus making it fail immedately) but based on custom programmatic logic, not simply if it can't parse a value into a numeric.